# Question about the definition of an affine curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ be a curve defined by a polynomial equation $f(x,y) = 0$, where $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is irreducible (and not necessarily non-singular). In the context I am interested in, application of Siegel's theorem, it just states ``genus is positive'' without any further explanation all the time. I realized I don't have a good understanding of this (the thing I had in mind was the genus degree formula $(d-1)(d-2)/2$ but it is valid only if $C$ is nonsingular projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$...)
I would appreciate if someone could please clarify me the following questions.

-If it just says genus, is it arithmetic genus or geometric genus?

-How does one define a genus of an affine curve?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

ps as mentioned in the comment, couple places that mention genus of an affine curve:

- https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Siegel_theorem
- https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/siegels-theorem-on-integral-points/

Comment: What is the “It” that says these things? Are you referring to a textbook or some other material?

Comment: @Arkady I will add to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of geometric genus for a smooth projective geometrically irreducible curve $C$ over a field $k$ is $\dim_k H^0(C,\Omega_{C/k})$, and this is extended to curves which are not necessarily smooth or projective in the following manner: any finitely generated field extension of transcendence degree one $k\to K$ [determines a regular projective curve](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BY1) over $k$ which is unique up to isomorphism, so we may define the geometric genus for any curve to be the geometric genus of a smooth projective model which is birational to our curve (NB: there's some trickiness here when you're dealing with a curve over an imperfect field which I am going to gloss over, see for instance [0BYE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BYE) if you need this). This is the genus that is being referred to in your post.

As far as "which genus", arithmetic genus isn't typically defined for non-proper schemes: the definition of the arithmetic genus for a proper scheme $X$ over a field $k$ is $$(-1)^{\dim X}(\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)-1)=(-1)^{\dim X}\left(-1+\sum_{i=0} (-1)^i\dim_k H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\right)$$ and if $X$ is not proper, there's no guarantee that $\dim_k H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is finite. So if you're dealing with a non-proper curve and someone says genus, they can't mean arithmetic genus. Further, if $X$ is a smooth curve, the geometric genus and arithmetic genus are the same by Serre duality - so the only time you'd need to worry about the disagreement of these genera for curves is when you are dealing with a proper singular curve, and the author should specify here.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you! I came to the conclusion that in both posts it is the geometric genus.